# Power BI | Measure that uses MIN or MINX in tandem with IF and/or circumvent text and numbers incompatibility with measures

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I'm pretty new to Power BI, and what I'm trying to do is replicate an excel table in PBI. The following is a table of both what I have in PBI and What I want.

I'm trying to get the gap or cushion for a medical agenda, and also to get the actual date. In excel, I get the nearest appointment and the farthest appointment, which changes if I filter by medical professional. I did it thanks to the subtotal function.

In italic, there's data I haven't gotten yet (in excel, I've randomly assigned it), but because of the message:

> Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns

I've noticed that it's problematic to mix text with numerical values with the `IF` function. If it could be crcumvented, it would be great, but in the end, it will be better to use 1 and 0 to determine if a slot has been taken.

So, instead of a "not available" message, I'm currently forcing the date to be the actual 0 of the system if the appointment has already gone by, **and I hope to add the condition that if the slot is taken, it also returns 0**

However, **my main concern** is that, I don't know how to make a MEASURE that returns the minimum and maximum Open Slot.

| Area | Profesional | Slot | ¿Taken? | Gap | Open Slot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Area | John Doe | 15-dic-2020 13:00 | *no* | `e.g: -131,18` | 15-dic-1899 00:00 |
| Area | Jane Doe | 30-apr-2021 10:00 | *yes* | `Slot - NOW()` | *15-dic-1899 00:00* |
| Area | Jane Doe | 30-apr-2021 11:00 | *no* | `Slot - NOW()` | 30-apr-2021 11:00 |
| Area | Jane Doe | 30-jun-2021 10:00 | *no* | `Slot - NOW()` | 30-jun-2021 10:00 |

For the table `APPOINTMENT`, I tried to create the measure:

`Next_Slot = MINX(APPOINTMENT, IF(APPOINTMENT[Open_Slot] > NOW(), APPOINTMENT[Open_Slot], "No Appointment Available))` but all I'm getting is the actual minimum value, which is *15-dic-1899 00:00*

I'm guessing that I either have to:

(1) circumvent the text and numbers issue in the `IF` function, so that I get the "Not Available" instead of *15-dic-1899 00:00* in the last column, and the `MINX` function will hopefully return the actual slot that is both free and further down in time than `NOW()`, ignoring the non-numerical values.

(2) actually make the `MINX` function take into consideration the `IF` function so that it ignores the dates earlier than `NOW()`.

And what I ultimately want to show in the dashboard is:

(1) The next available slot, and the farthest available slot
(2) The time between `NOW()` and the two above
(3) being able to filter by Area and By proffesional, and other additional non-numerical

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably missed something but in this approach all results would be text:

[image]

Data:

```
| Area  |   Profesional   |      Slot      | Taken |
:-------:-----------------:----------------:-------:
| Area1 | John Doe        | 12/15/20 13:00 | no    |
| Area1 | Jane Doe        | 4/30/21 10:00  | yes   |
| Area1 | Jane Doe        | 4/30/21 11:00  | no    |
| Area1 | Jane Doe        | 6/30/21 10:00  | no    |
| Area2 | Emma Stone      | 1/1/21 10:00   | yes   |
| Area2 | Emma Stone      | 5/1/21 15:00   | yes   |
| Area2 | Emma Stone      | 5/1/21 15:10   | no    |
| Area2 | Emma Stone      | 5/1/21 15:20   | no    |
| Area2 | Henry Cavill    | 2/1/21 15:00   | yes   |
| Area2 | Henry Cavill    | 5/8/21 10:50   | no    |
| Area2 | Henry Cavill    | 5/8/21 11:00   | yes   |
| Area2 | Henry Cavill    | 5/8/21 11:20   | no    |
| Area2 | Anya Taylor-Joy | 4/27/21 8:50   | no    |
| Area2 | Anya Taylor-Joy | 4/28/21 7:30   | no    |
```

Measures:

```
NextAvailableSlot := 
VAR ClosestAvailableDate = CALCULATE(MIN(Appointments[Slot]),Appointments[Taken]="no")
RETURN
IF(HASONEVALUE(Appointments[Profesional]),
    IF(
        ClosestAvailableDate>NOW(),
        FORMAT(ClosestAvailableDate,
        "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"),
        "No Appointment Available"
        )
)


FarthestAvailableSlot := 
VAR FarthestAvailableDate = CALCULATE(MAX(Appointments[Slot]),Appointments[Taken]="no")
RETURN
IF(HASONEVALUE(Appointments[Profesional]),
    IF(
        FarthestAvailableDate>NOW(),
        FORMAT(FarthestAvailableDate,
        "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"),
        "No Appointment Available"
        )
)

NAS_Gap_Days_Hours_ISH := 
VAR ClosestAvailableDate = CALCULATE(MIN(Appointments[Slot]),Appointments[Taken]="no")
VAR NAS = IF(HASONEVALUE(Appointments[Profesional]),
    IF(
        ClosestAvailableDate>NOW(),
        ClosestAvailableDate
        )
)
//Custom Time Diff Pattern from: 
//https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Calculate-time-in-Days-Hours-amp-Minutes/td-p/406017
//CALCULATIONS
VAR DIFF = NAS - NOW()
VAR NumOfMinutes = DIFF * 24
    * 60
VAR DAYS =
    IF ( DIFF >= 1, INT ( DIFF ), BLANK () )
VAR HOURS =
    INT ( ( DIFF - DAYS ) * 24 )
VAR MINUTES = NumOfMinutes
    - ( DAYS * 24
    * 60 )
    - ( HOURS * 60 ) 
//TEXTS
VAR DaysText =
    IF ( DAYS > 1, FORMAT ( DAYS, "00" ) & "days" )
VAR HoursText =
    FORMAT ( HOURS, "00" ) & "hrs"
VAR MinutesText =
    FORMAT ( MINUTES, "00" ) & "mins"
//
RETURN
IF(
    NOT ISBLANK(NAS),
        COMBINEVALUES ( " ", DaysText, HoursText, MinutesText )
    )

FAS_Gap_Days_Hours_ISH := 
VAR FarthestAvailableDate = CALCULATE(MAX(Appointments[Slot]),Appointments[Taken]="no")
VAR FAS = IF(HASONEVALUE(Appointments[Profesional]),
    IF(
        FarthestAvailableDate>NOW(),
        FarthestAvailableDate
        )
)
//Custom Time Diff Pattern from: 
//https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Calculate-time-in-Days-Hours-amp-Minutes/td-p/406017
//CALCULATIONS
VAR DIFF = FAS - NOW()
VAR NumOfMinutes = DIFF * 24
    * 60
VAR DAYS =
    IF ( DIFF >= 1, INT ( DIFF ), BLANK () )
VAR HOURS =
    IF( INT ( ( DIFF - DAYS ) * 24 ) >= 1, INT ( ( DIFF - DAYS ) * 24 ),BLANK () ) 
VAR MINUTES = NumOfMinutes
    - ( DAYS * 24
    * 60 )
    - ( HOURS * 60 ) 
//TEXTS
VAR DaysText =
    IF ( DAYS > 1, FORMAT ( DAYS, "00" ) & "days" )
VAR HoursText =
    IF ( HOURS > 1,FORMAT ( HOURS, "00" ) & "hrs")
VAR MinutesText =
    FORMAT ( MINUTES, "00" ) & "mins"
//
RETURN
IF(
    NOT ISBLANK(FAS),
        COMBINEVALUES ( " ", DaysText, HoursText, MinutesText )
    )
```

Comment: jprzd, I appreciate the solution. I'll take it into consideration. Regarding the negative differences, I would add an `IF()` to evaluate if the `NextAvailableSlot` is lower than `NOW()`, in which case, the date is "replaced" with `NOW()`.

Nevertheless, would you happen to know if my suggested approach is feasible or not?

I won't mark it as a solution just yet, because I still want to see if I can get the solution with a conditioned `MINX()`

P.D: ¿which visual did you pick for your example?

Again, thanks.

Comment: I used a matrix visual and disabled the SubTotal Row. There is no problem in marking or not marking the answer as correct. Don't worry. Also, sorry for my curiosity but what would be the exact meaning of this condition,?NextAvailableSlot < NOW(). For example: If NOW() is 15:25 and the minimum value not taken is 11:30 and there are two slots taken at 15:20 and 15:30, the current function does not return NOW() because there is a slot scheduled for 15:30 and another taken during 15:25. What you say is possible but I repeat from my curiosity and lack of information, it defies logic.

Comment: @jprdz, `NextAvailableSlot < NOW()` is the logical condition to ignore all slots prior to the present day and time, REGARDLESS of whether a pacient took it or not.

Comment: What about John Doe? NextAvailableSlot > NOW() already returns "No Appointment available" since there are no available slots. Should John Doe's case return NOW()? I would appreciate it if you would expand the sample data with the possible scenarios, please. I'll check them later.

Comment: It's fine that John Doe returns No appointment available. In excel, the IF function evaluated 2 conditions, (1) have the date and time already passed, and (2) is it taken or not.

Comment: The condition "(2) is it taken or not" is covered within the ClosestAvailableDate variable. {Appointments [Taken] = "no"} inside CALCULATE, it is added to the filters coming from the visualization (Professional & Area) making the Appointments[Slot] column reference within MIN(Appointments [Slot]) return the dates that comply with the conditions:
[1] Professional = ProfessionalName, [2] Area = AreaName (filter context from visualization) [3] Appointments [Taken] = "no" (filter context added from CALCULATE). Then MIN(Appointments[Slot]) returns the lowest date within that filtered column.

Comment: So far, the partial result for John Does is 12/15/2020 13:00 and for Jane Doe it is 4/30/2021 11:00. Finally, "IF (ClosestAvailableDate> NOW () ..." returns "No Appointment Available" for John Doe and 4/30/2021 11:00 for Jane Doe. All conditions would be covered